# Parallel arecord statements using GNU Parallel

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gnu-parallel

I am new to Linux. I want to record from 2 microphones simultaneously. I know how to do separately. Some lag is tolerable. Is it possible to do that using arecord with GNU Parallel?
I am using 2 USB soundcards.

Comment: Do you know how to do the two recordings individually/separately? If so, click `edit` under your question and paste that in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I couldn't get to do this yet. I will try it asap. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its simplest, you would get the list of devices with:

```
arecord --list-devices
```

Then, assuming your sound cards have hardware ids `1,0` and `2,0`, you could do:

```
parallel --dry-run arecord -D hw:{},0 -d 5 {}.wav ::: 1 2
```

**Sample Output**

```
arecord -D hw:1,0 -d 5 1.wav
arecord -D hw:2,0 -d 5 2.wav
```

If that looks correct, run again but omitting `--dry-run`.